# extract information from field using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using Logstash to parse an XML file, I have something like that:

`<Value Obj="SPM=med48610,RGN=region1,AZ=zone1,VCM=med-4861-0-storage-vm0,Link=eth1">`

I am looking for a way to get a new field with `SPM` which contains the username and another field to indicate the number of my VM `vm0` and also the type `storage` (VCM=med-4861-0-storage-vm0)
For the moment I can just get one field that contains all the `Obj`

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom logstash filter plugin to achieve your target.
[How to write custom logstash plugin](https://medium.com/@AnushkaSandaru1/custom-logstash-plugin-b5cf0bac4891)